# Adding an image in tweet composer

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric plugin to compose a tweet that shares a combination of text and image. I want to share the image directly from the link as follows:

```
private void composetweet() {
        TweetComposer.Builder builder=new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
                .text("This is made by saptak das")
                .image(Uri.parse("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/09/21/16/2C96F60E00000578-0-image-a-126_1442848442984.jpg"));
        builder.show();
    }
```

The problem is that the text is parsed into the tweet successfully but in case of the image, a toast comes up saying **Image could not be loaded**

Comment: https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html - If you see the documentation, there is a line which says **The image Uri should be a file Uri (i.e. file://absolute_path scheme) to a local file.** So yes, Image should be in your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download image on your device (I used [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for this) and then get its uri and pass it to TweetComposer. Here is solution:

```
Glide.with(Context)
            .load(imageUri)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                //calling when downloading finished
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    //creating new file and getting its uri
                    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    file = new File(path + "/DemoImage.jpg");
                    if (!file.getParentFile().exists())
                        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    try {

                        if (file.exists())
                            file.delete();
                        file.createNewFile();

                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                        fileOutputStream.flush();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    if (file != null)
                        makeShare(Uri.fromFile(file));
                    else
                        makeShare(null);

                }
            });
```

Here is makeShare(Uri uri) method code:

```
void makeShare(Uri imagePath){
    if (imagePath != null){
        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(viewInterface.getContext())
                .text("Your message")
                .image(imagePath);
        builder.show();
    }else {
        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(viewInterface.getContext())
                .text("Your message");
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Also, note, that you need to request permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```